# Create QIcon from resources.qrc file

Tags: python, qt, resources, pyqt4, qicon

I have a `resources.qrc` file that looks like this:

```
<RCC>
  <qresource prefix="/plugins/fw_einsatz">
    <file>base_aerial.png</file>
    <file>base_alkis.png</file>
    <file>adr.png</file>
    <file>gps_coord.png</file>
    <file>road.png</file>
    <file>route.png</file>
    <file>icon.png</file>
  </qresource>
</RCC>
```

I want to create a QIcon from these resources with

```
icon = QIcon('qrc:///route.png')
```

and then put it on a QPushButton with

```
self.pushButton_toggle_epl_view.setIcon(icon)
```

but no Icon is displayed. What am I missing? Wrong path?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your path is wrong, try this instead :

```py
icon = QIcon(":/plugins/fw_einsatz/route.png")
```